# When is remove_at event in Google Maps API v3 triggered?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, jquery, addeventlistener

I am working on google map api v3 and want to add a feature of editing the polyline. As of the google documentation. There are 3 events fired when a polyline is in edit mode.

1. insert_at
2. set_at
3. remove_at

I know when first two events are fired and am able to get the edited coordinates as well. I also want to delete a node but not sure how it works?. Can anyone tell me when will the event "remove_at" will be fired ?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://code.google.com/intl/cs/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MVCArray) these events belong to class `google.maps.MVCArray`. You can find there also a description of `remove_at` event:

> This event is fired when removeAt() is called. The event passes the
>   index that was passed to removeAt() and the element that was removed
>   from the array.

But I'm not sure you can use these events to handle changes while editing the Polyline. That's very interesting, please let us know if it works and how!

Comment: Thank you Sir Tomas. I was aware of the fact that it is triggered when removeAt() is called, but wanted to know when this event is fired while editing the polyline as other two events are triggered. Well I have worked around it.
I assign a "rightclick" listener to all the nodes in the polyline and remove the node when this right click event is fired, which works as I wanted it to. I now have it fully working. Thanks :)

Comment: I really expected both polygons and polylines to except the same path events and behave the same ... but nooooo

Comment: @JohnnyDarvall, quite typical :) can you be more specific? How are polygons different?

Comment: I retract my comment. It does in fact work the same. I expected the events to still work after adding a new path - thousand pardons.

Answer (score 2):

'remove_at' will be triggered when you undo an edit to an existing overlay that results in control point(s) getting removed.

I've created a [fiddle to demonstrate](http://jsfiddle.net/HoffZ/Zu55b/) this.

From the fiddle:

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(60.629765, 6.424094);
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

var drawMan = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    map: map,
    drawingControl: false,
    polygonOptions: {
        editable: true,
        draggable: true
    }
});

drawMan.setDrawingMode(google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON);

google.maps.event.addListener(drawMan, 'overlaycomplete', function (event) {
    // When draw mode is set to null you can edit the polygon you just drawed
    drawMan.setDrawingMode(null);

    google.maps.event.addListener(event.overlay.getPath(), 'remove_at', function () {
        alert('remove_at triggered');
    });
});
```