# Request further information regarding: When is remove_at event in Google Maps API v3 triggered?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, addeventlistener

It appears that there is a workaround solution to the original question that was posed here at stackoverflow:

[When is remove_at event in Google Maps API v3 triggered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282623/when-is-remove-at-event-in-google-maps-api-v3-triggered)

It would be greatly appreciated if I could see the code or a code example of how "to assign a "rightclick" listener to all the nodes in the polyline and remove the node when this right click event is fired."

I am attempting to do the same thing, and that is to remove a node in the polyline when said node is "rightclicked."  Unfortunately, I haven't hit upon the correct combination within my application code.  Seeing the code or an example of the code from a successful solution would be greatly appreciated and help me out immensely.

thank you,
rtp01

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is possible to assign events to a polyline node, but you can add a marker object at the same location of the node and assign an event to that.

I altered Google's `polyline-complex.html` example to also remove nodes as well as add them.

In this example Google adds markers to a map when the user left-clicks on the map and then connects the markers with a polyline.  I added a right-click listener to the marker that removes the node from the polyline.

Here is the code: (Here is a [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/MwVLG/) to see the full code working)

```
//after the marker is created in the addLatLng function
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'rightclick', removeLatLng);
```

...

```
//function to remove node.
function removeLatLng(event) {
    //remove the marker from the map
    this.setMap(null);
    //get the polyline array
    var path = poly.getPath();
    //iterate over the array and remove the point that matches the marker coords.
    path.forEach(function(element, idx) {
        if (event.latLng == element) {
            path.removeAt(idx);
        }
    });
}
```

The trick is you need to have the array index of the node you want removed.  Without having the marker the right-click event may not return the exact coords of the node and make it difficult to find the index.

If you don't like the marker graphic for use as a node you can customize the icon property with a custom *.png file to represent the node.

Comment: Thank you. Was coming to that conclusion. Was also hoping I did not have to go down that path (no pun intended) of having to place a marker with an event listener on each node of the polyline.  It appears that deleting nodes directly from a polyline has not been implemented as of yet in the new [Drawing Library](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#drawing_tools).  thanks again, rtp01

Comment: If you read through the [Drawing Library](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#drawing_tools), if you haven't yet, you'll see that some events are supported on the polylines.  I am using the set_at and insert_at events, but again, it doesn't appear that removing nodes is supported as "easily" as the other events are at this time within the [Drawing Library](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#drawing_tools).  thanks again

Comment: It also appears I'm not the only one asking google about deleting nodes. [google maps group](http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_thread/thread/3d5072c41f4f502c/825cba64211f7ce9?lnk=gst&q=drawingmanager#825cba64211f7ce9).

Comment: Oh yea I agree, I hope this feature gets implemented soon.  It will make a lot of applications easier to deal with.